# how to solve $m$ in inequality involving $m \log m $?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, special-functions

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. I am trying to prove that  if $m \log m >0.53n$, then

$$m>\frac{0.53n}{\log 0.53n},$$

where $m$ is not necessarily bigger than $n$.

**My attempt:**
First recall the Lambert function denoted by
$W(x)$ which is the inverse fonction of $xe^x$, i.e.,
$W(xe^x)=x$, $W$ is increasing because $xe^x$ is increasing.

As $ m \log m =\log m e^{\log m} $,
by applying $W$  we get
$ m>W(0.53n)$.

How to prove such inequality?

**Edit question.**
After  seeing the comments
It seems that the second inequality is not true for any value of $n$ and $m$. So we have to put some condition on $n$ and $m$.

Here is my second attempt:
Assume $n$ is large enough s.t. $\log 0.53 n >1$.
Then if $m<0.53n$ then
$\log m <\log 0.53n$, hence

$$m \log 0.53n >m \log m>0.53n $$
So we get

$$ m>\frac{0.53n}{\log 0.53n}, $$

If $0.53n<m$ then
$m>0.53n>\frac{0.53n}{\log 0.53n} $

The last inequality is true By our assumption on $n$ so  we get

$$ m>\frac{0.53n}{\log 0.53n},$$

if $0.53n=m$.

By replacing it in the  first inequality we get
$n>6$.

So the inequality is true assuming $n>6$ .

Is my second attempt  right?

Comment: Try it with $m=2,n=2$.

Comment: The first inequality is true and the second is false in a small number of cases.  Specifically, it seems like the thing you're trying to prove fails for $(m,n)=(3,3)$, and also for $n=2$ and $2 \le m \le 18$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx ok assume only when the inequality two is true but how to go from $m \log m $ to $m $ this is the question

Comment: @AsterPhoenix It is very hard to read your question and solution the way it is now.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak is it clear now?

Comment: @AsterPhoenix Yes, it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fact 1.** Let $m, n\in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$
with $n \ge 4$. If $m\ln m > c n$,
then $m > \frac{cn}{\ln(cn)}$ where $c = 0.53$.

**Proof.**

If $n = 4, 5$, it is easy.

In the following, assume that $n \ge 6$.

We have $\ln(cn) > 1$. Thus, we have
$\ln \frac{cn}{\ln(cn)} < \ln (cn)$ and
$$\frac{cn}{\ln(cn)}\ln \frac{cn}{\ln(cn)} < cn.$$

Thus, we have
$$m\ln m > c n > \frac{cn}{\ln(cn)}\ln \frac{cn}{\ln(cn)}.$$

Since $x \mapsto x\ln x$ is strictly increasing on $x \ge 1$, using $\frac{cn}{\ln(cn)} > 1$, we have
$$m > \frac{cn}{\ln(cn)}.$$

We are done.

Comment: I didn't understand how $\frac{cn}{\log cn } \log \frac{cn}{\log cn}<cn $ implies the desired inequality?

Comment: @AsterPhoenix Which step?

Comment: ,$m$ didn't show up in the steps how it did end up in the conclusion?

Comment: @AsterPhoenix OK. I skip this step: $m\ln m > c n > \frac{cn}{\ln(cn)}\ln \frac{cn}{\ln(cn)}$. I will edit it.